# sql select returns duplicate rows because of joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I am doing a join in select statement and it returns duplicate professional id because of the join.

```
Select P.ProfessionalID,  P.ProfessionalName , S.SpecialtyName
    from Professionals P, ProfessionalSpecialtyRelation PR,  Specialties S 
where
    ( P.ProfessionalName Like '%arif%' OR P.ProfessionalSurname Like '%%'
    )
    And P.ProfessionalID = PR.ProfessionalID
    AND P.ProfessionalID = POR.ProfessionalID
    AND PR.SpecialtyID = S.SpecialtyID
```

If Prof has two Specialities, it returns that Prof twice. How can I avoid that? what is the best way to do it?

Comment: what do you want the result to be if they have more than one speciality?

Comment: I want to get only one row for that Prof. I need unique IDs

Comment: So you only want one speciality selected?

Comment: You joined one to many, so you get many. It's not a duplicate. You need to define which of the many specialities a professional could have, you want to show.

Comment: Oh and whats with the horribly outdated join syntax? See BF's answer for the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return one speciality then you can use an aggregate (max/min) function:

```
Select P.ProfessionalID,  
  P.ProfessionalName, 
  max(S.SpecialtyName) SpecialtyName
from Professionals P
inner join ProfessionalSpecialtyRelation PR
  on P.ProfessionalID = PR.ProfessionalID
  -- and P.ProfessionalID = POR.ProfessionalID  You are not joining to a table with POR alias
inner join Specialties S 
  on PR.SpecialtyID = S.SpecialtyID
where P.ProfessionalName Like '%arif%' 
  OR P.ProfessionalSurname Like '%%'
group by P.ProfessionalID, P.ProfessionalName;
```

Or since you are using SQL Server you can also use the `row_number()` function to return only one row for each professional:

```
select ProfessionalID,
  ProfessionalName,
  SpecialtyName
from 
(
  Select P.ProfessionalID,  
    P.ProfessionalName, 
    S.SpecialtyName,
    row_number() over(partition by P.ProfessionalID order by S.SpecialtyName) rn
  from Professionals P
  inner join ProfessionalSpecialtyRelation PR
    on P.ProfessionalID = PR.ProfessionalID
    -- and P.ProfessionalID = POR.ProfessionalID  You are not joining to a table with POR alias
  inner join Specialties S 
    on PR.SpecialtyID = S.SpecialtyID
  where P.ProfessionalName Like '%arif%' 
    OR P.ProfessionalSurname Like '%%'
) d
where rn = 1;
```

Note: I changed the query to use ANSI JOIN syntax (INNER JOIN) instead of the comma separated list with the joins in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

You don't explain what is the speciality you want for your professor having two specialities.
You need to group by professor, and apply an aggregate function on the specialities. Depending on the aggregate function, you will get different results:

```
SELECT P.ProfessionalID
     , P.ProfessionalName 
     , MAX(S.SpecialtyName)
FROM Professionals P
    INNER JOIN ProfessionalSpecialtyRelation PR
        ON P.ProfessionalID = PR.ProfessionalID
            INNER JOIN Specialties S 
                ON PR.SpecialtyID = S.SpecialtyID
WHERE P.ProfessionalName Like '%arif%' 
OR P.ProfessionalSurname Like '%%'
GROUP BY P.ProfessionalID,  P.ProfessionalName
```

With the `MAX` function, you will get the maxium of the specialty, in term of string.

Note that you should write your joins explicitly with `JOIN` clause, instead of writing it implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

remove S from join, and use sub-query to get result with comma.
Use with clause or other ideas.
I hope it well help you.
Best of luck.